# How can I make an app that taps into all incoming push messages on Android?

Tags: android

Here's the use case: I want to create a statistics tool that lists all incoming push messages on a given phone, their message text, when they arrived and their source. *clarification:* I need 100% access to the data as I'm creating my own presentation tool for private use. It's not to be a consumer app.

I'm thinking I can achieve this by creating an app that somehow listens to *all* incoming intents of type `com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE` and then analyzing the contents of those. Now I believe that is not possible with the security and intent model of stock Android. But is there anyway around this either with a stock rooted phone, or do I even have to go further and fork and modify AOSP?

Other options I can think of is to monitor the visual notification center itself, if that has an API (which I doubt).

Any suggestions are welcome. I am not intimidated by difficult tasks. Yet my knowledge is limited to Java Android coding - I know little of AOSP or the NDK, but I'd be willing to learn if this is the path I must take.

(Sorry if this is a very broad question, I'll accept the answer that gives me the easiest path to a solution)

Comment: I think you are trying to make app like [Snowball](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.snowball.app&hl=en) ?

Comment: Well yea I want to know how they did it :) See clarification of my use case. This gives me hope at least!

Comment: I too want to know the way to implement it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out it wasn't all that difficult. You need an app with `minSdkVersion=18` and then you can implement a [NotificationListenerService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService.html) which listens for created or deleted notifications, or you can poll for the currently visible.

Caveat: You need explicit persmission from the user to read notifications other than your own.

[image: Settings - security - notification access]

Basically what you do is 1. Extend the `NotificationListenerInterface` and override the `onNotificationPosted` like this:

```
@Override
public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification notif) {
    Bundle extras = notif.getNotification().extras;
    String packageName = notif.getPackageName();
    if (extras != null) {
        String title = "" + extras.getCharSequence(Notification.EXTRA_TITLE);
        String description = "" + extras.getCharSequence(Notification.EXTRA_TEXT);
        // Do whatever you want to do with the data
    }
}
```

In addition you need to register the service in the manifest:

```
<application>
    <!-- (...) -->
    <service android:name=".YourListenerClassName"
        android:label="@string/app_name"            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
</application>
```